# MongoDB not working after update OS Catalina

Tags: mongodb

I updated the Mac OS Catalina and don't work mongodb, I tried reinstalling it and it still doesn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBb80.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please [edit] the question to replace or augment the image with the text that it contains. Images are not searchable (which hurts your chances for getting an answer), nor are they accessible (which limits who can answer your question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Can I ask questions about installation in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338203/can-i-ask-questions-about-installation-in-so) Questions about software tools commonly used by programmers must be **a practical, answerable problem unique to software development.**